# Default MacVim colorscheme gets loaded last in scriptnames - can't load any colorschemes

Tags: vim, macvim

`:scriptnames` on MacVim gives me (in order):

```
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/vimrc
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/defaults.vim
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/synload.vim
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/syncolor.vim
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/filetype.vim
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/menu.vim
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/autoload/paste.vim
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/ftplugin.vim
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/indent.vim
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/getscriptPlu
gin.vim
 /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/gzip.vim
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/logiPat.vim
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/manpager.vim
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/matchparen.v
im
 16: /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/netrwPlugin.
vim
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/rrhelper.vim
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/spellfile.vi
m
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/tarPlugin.vi
m
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/tohtml.vim
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/vimballPlugi
n.vim
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/gvimrc
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/colors/macvim.vim
```

I edited the second to last `gvimrc` file to reflect the colorscheme that I have in the correct directory (https://github.com/romainl/Apprentice), but the colors are always wrong and the `macvim.vim` default colorscheme always gets loaded last

Answer (score 0):

```
colorscheme apprentice
```

can go in either of these three files:

```
~/.vimrc
~/.vim/vimrc
~/.gvimrc
~/.vim/gvimrc
```

and *nowhere* else.